# Regex for inconsistent html color codes

Tags: regex

I am developing a script that will be used as a pre-commit git hook that will enforce a specific element of coding style: 
In an html color code of format #mmm or #mmmmmm use either all small or all capital letters.

I need a regex that

will match:

- *#35A5b7* -> length 6, valid hexa, **mixed case**: capital A, small b
- *#aF4* -> length 3, valid hexa, **mixed case**: small a, capital F

will **not** match:

- *#35A5B7* -> length 6, valid hexa, no mix (capital letters only)
- *#35a5b7* -> length 6, valid hexa, no mix (small letters only)
- *#af4* -> length 3, valid hexa, no mix
- *#AF4* -> length 3, valid hexa, no mix
- *#s99* -> letter not hexa
- *#abc9* -> length neither 3 nor 6
- *#367* -> no letters involved

I have a regex that cannot satisfy the length constraint and matches too much

```
[a-fA-F\d]*[a-f][a-fA-F\d]*[A-F][a-fA-F\d]*|[a-fA-F\d]*[A-F][a-fA-F\d]*[a-f][a-fA-F\d]*
                                           ^ or here
```

The reason for not matching invalid color codes (length not 3 or 6, letter not hexa) is I want to minimize the situation where a commit is rejected because somebody used tokens like like *#s23* in comments (may be valid business related references).

I know I can use negative lookbehind on `color`, `background`, `background-color` and all places where a color is expected, but before I go there, is there something evidently simple that I am missing?

Any flavor of regex welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my stab at it ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6TMP8A/1)):

```
#(?!([0-9A-F]+|[0-9a-f]+)\b)(?i:[0-9A-F]{3}){1,2}\b
```

The first group is a negative lookahead that will *exclude* any sequence of consistent letters (either `[0-9A-F]+` or `[0-9a-f]+`). The second block will match any sequence of 3 or 6 hexadecimal digits.

Note: The `i` in the second group applies the case-insensitive flag to that group alone, so it's equivalent to `(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{3})`.